# Map ports on edge server to internal SSH services

Tags: linux, network-programming, iptables

I have a network.

There's an edge server with a public IP address.

There are multiple internal services `192.168.0.{1..255}` with SSH running on port 22 that can be accessed via a private network from the edge server.

I have clients connecting from outside the network to the edge server on port range `30001-30255`. I need to map these connections to internal SSH services like so:

- `ssh -p 30001 myedgeserver.com` -> `192.6.0.1:22`
- `ssh -p 30002 myedgeserver.com` -> `192.6.0.2:22`
- ...
- `ssh -p 30255 myedgeserver.com` -> `192.6.0.255:22`

Can this be achieved with *iptables*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You make a nat for each of the 255 ports. I am unaware that you can do it in one line. So 255 lines like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 30001 -j DNAT \
  --to 192.6.0.1:22
```

Comment: Looks good. Just doesn't work across interfaces. The public connections are from eth0 and internal is eth1. What do I need to change?